# How to make a label fade in or out in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fadein, fadeout, fading

I am looking to make a label fade in, in `viewDidLoad()`, and then after a timer is at 3 fade out.  I am not familiar with the `fadein` or `fadeout` functions.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the view has loaded, it may not be visible to the user when `viewDidLoad` is called. This means you might find your animations appears to have already started when you witness it. To overcome this issue, you'll want to start your animation in `viewDidAppear` instead.

As for the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions - they don't exist. You'll need to write them yourself. Thankfully, it's very easy to do this. Something like the below might be good enough.

```
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UIView, delay: NSTimeInterval) {

    let animationDuration = 0.25

    // Fade in the view
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
        view.alpha = 1
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in

            // After the animation completes, fade out the view after a delay

            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: delay, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                view.alpha = 0
                },
                completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

My suggestion is to leverage Swift extensions to make the code a bit more modular and easy to use. For example, if you want to make multiple labels fadein/out or one label to fade in/out on multiple views, you would have to pass the animateWithDuration methods everywhere, which can be a hassle. A cleaner alternative is to create a file called UIView.swift (our UIView extension). Add the following code to this file:

```
import Foundation

extension UIView {


func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)  }

func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 3.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
}

}
```

Now you can add fadeIn/fadeout functionality to any child of UIView (e.g., UILabel, UIImage, etc). Inside of your viewDidLoad() function, you can add :

```
self.statusLabel.alpha = 0
self.statusLabel.text = "Sample Text Here"
self.myLabel.fadeIn(completion: {
        (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.myLabel.fadeOut()
        })
```

Now, you can use this sample code for Image views, labels, text views, scroll views, or any child of UIView as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Very clean and abstracted away. Thanks.

Comment: This is an awesome resolution to this problem.

Comment: This looks great! Thank you. FYI the "completion" parameter needs an @escaping closure.

Answer (score 11):

**Answer updated for Swift 3 - Using extension**

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 3.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
self.statusLabel.alpha = 0
self.statusLabel.text = "Sample Text Here"
self.myLabel.fadeIn(completion: {
        (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.myLabel.fadeOut()
        })
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer posted by Troy Nunnally a year earlier?

Answer (score 4):

Update Swift 3.1  - on @Andy code

```
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UIView, delay: TimeInterval) {
        let animationDuration = 0.25

        // Fade in the view
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
            view.alpha = 1
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in

            // After the animation completes, fade out the view after a delay

            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: { () -> Void in
                view.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The edit button is there for a reason. Copy pasting an answer just to modify the syntax slightly is not good.

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 4.2

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 3.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

This worked well for me. I placed the label inside the "cardHeaderView".

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardHeaderView: UIView!
```

Place this inside the "viewDidAppear". I went with a delay of zero so the animation would start right away.

```
fadeViewInThenOut(view: cardHeaderView, delay: 0)
```

Here is the function.

```
func fadeViewInThenOut(view : UIView, delay: TimeInterval) {

    let animationDuration = 1.5

    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: delay, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse, UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat], animations: {
        view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)

}
```